# How to use xampp with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, yii, xampp, freetds

I am using xampp on a Linux server. My `phpinfo()` function says that I have FreeTDS
[image: Default configuration]

Now when I connect with Yii, its gives me the error:

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver
```

The only thing I installed is xampp v1.8.3-3 X64 for Linux (centos).

Did I miss something, or something extra I need to install ??

**EDIT:**

```
my Yii connection: dblib:host=MY_HOST_IP;dbname=MY_DB
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have downloaded a dblib extension and moved it to php extension folder and tried again.
This is the new message from the server.

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)
```

Comment: Have you installed freetds?

Comment: It is already installed with xampp (as noted in the picture)

Comment: Check your connection string or refer here [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/40979-cdbconnection-could-not-find-driver-mssql/)